# How to estimate number of transactions on the Lightning Network

Tags: lightning-network

I would like to estimate the transaction volume (number of transactions) on Lightning Network.
Has anyone done any work towards that?

An idea I have is simply look at the reporting nodes out there average them out an extrapolate. I have not validated that. Seeing first if something already exists.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to estimate this, unless you're a very well connected node (in the sense that you route a lot of transactions).

Answer (score 0):

---

This is an excellent question, but its clarity is a bit elusive to me.

The Lightning Network comprises a combination of public and private nodes. While you can gauge the number of nodes that interact with your node, it's challenging to determine the total number of payments processed by the Lightning Network.

To elaborate:

- The gossip map, shared among public nodes, provides a comprehensive view of the network. To obtain the metrics you're interested in, you'd need to oversee all the primary nodes within the network. However, there's always the uncertainty of private nodes routing through public ones.
- Personally, I believe that nodes not keen on routing should remain private. This implies they won't appear on the gossip map. Unless you have a private connection with these nodes, you remain unaware of their existence. Consequently, gathering data about these nodes becomes exceedingly difficult, as it is difficult to prove their existence.

---